# Issue in next auth v5 session in next js 14

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I have an error in next auth v5 session in my next js 14 (app router).

Here is the error in console:

```
       GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session 500 (Internal Server Error)
fetchData @ client.js:32
getSession @ react.js:87
__NEXTAUTH._getSession @ react.js:245
handle @ react.js:285
app-index.js:31 ClientFetchError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at fetchData (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/client.js:50:22)
    at async getSession (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/react.js:102:21)
```

Here is my `ath.config.ts` in root directory:

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    error: "/error",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
  },

  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, email, profile, credentials }) {
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {

      session.user = token as any;

      return session;
    },

    async jwt({ token, user, session, account, profile }) {


      return { ...token, ...user };
    },

    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/account");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/account", nextUrl));
      }

      const isOnLoginPage = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login");
      if (isOnLoginPage) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return Response.redirect(new URL("/", nextUrl));
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [],

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

Here is my `auth.ts` in root directory:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { z } from "zod";
import { apibaseUrl } from "./apiConfig";

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        phoneNumber: { label: "Phone Number", type: "text" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const res = await fetch(`${apibaseUrl}/api-front/login-email`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          cache: "no-store",
        });
        let user = await res.json();
        console.log(user);

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(user?.error || "Authentication failed");
        }
        if (user.error === true) {
          throw new Error(user?.error || "Authentication failed");
        }
        user = user.data;
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

Here is my provider in for layout:

```
"use client";

import { NextUIProvider } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { ThemeProvider as NextThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <NextUIProvider navigate={router.push}>
      <NextThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="dark">
        <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
      </NextThemeProvider>
    </NextUIProvider>
  );
}
```

And here is my loyout.tsx

```
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import "@/app/globals.css";
import Providers from "@/app/provider";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "@/auth.config";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
config.autoAddCss = false;

export const metadata = {
  title: {
    default: "آکادمی ICF مارکت",
    template: "%s",
  },
  description: "Generated by create next app",
  icons: {
    icon: "",
  },
  openGraph: {
    title: "آکادمی ICF-Market",
    description: "Generated by create next app",

  },
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" dir="rtl" className="dark" style={{ colorScheme: "dark" }}>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"
        />
      </head>
      <body className="bg-white dark:bg-dark text-dark dark:text-white">
        <main className="mask">
          <NavBar />
          <Providers>{children}</Providers>
          <Footer />
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I appreciate to help me to solve it.

Comment: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7887

Comment: instead of `fetch` can u use `axios` to see if it works